# Using Thymeleaf in order to generate a URL with params and nested variables in it

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to use Thymeleaf in order to generate a URL with params.

```
<a th:with="baseUrl=${websiteContext} + '/#/email/activate/'" th:href="@{${baseUrl}(token=${member.token},newEmail=${requestedEmail})}" >Activate email</a>
```

generates the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/?token=1a964190-7807-47ee-a36b-e3712eeb24f4&newEmail=balteo%2540yahoo.fr#/email/activate/
```

However the literal string `/#/email/activate/` always ends up at the end of the url...

Note that I need the `#` within the url as my front end is based on angular.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the intended behaviour, according to [thymeleaf docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html):

> Fragment identifiers can be included in URLs, both with and without parameters. They will always be included at the URL base, so that:
>
> `<a th:href="@{/home#all_info(action='show')}">`
>
> …would output as:
>
> `<a href="/home?action=show#all_info">`

and also [this issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/289), where the reporter has the exact same problem as you have.

In case the link was dead, it was decided that the optional switch of behaviour will not be implemented for now, as URL parameters are intended for the server and should come before URL fragment (before `#`), and different client-side frameworks may require different way of passing parameters to them than simply by appending them after the fragment.

Citing also the proposed workaround:

> As a workaround, you can create your URL by appending your parameters manually, though you will have to perform URL-encoding of your parameter values yourself. For example, you can use a `|...|` *literal substitution* like: `@{|${resetTokenLink}?r=${token}|}`

BTW, I tried to reproduce your exact example and got the result of: `/#/email/activate/?token=1a964190-7807-47ee-a36b-e3712eeb24f4&newEmail=balteo%252540yahoo.fr`, which, I believe, you were expecting, but it was with thymeleaf 2.0.5. Then I tried again with the newest one and got your result...